# performSelector error with global function and AppDelegate class

Tags: ios, swift, function, global, performselector

I'm following [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW37) apple document and I'm trying to translate some of its parts in Swift language. I have this global function, with performSelector:

```
func RunLoopSourceScheduleRoutine(info:UnsafeMutableRawPointer? ,rl:CFRunLoop? , mode:CFRunLoopMode?)  {

let obj :  RunLoopSource = Unmanaged<RunLoopSource>.fromOpaque(info!).takeUnretainedValue()
let del = UIApplication.shared
let theContext = RunLoopContext(withSource: obj, andLoop: rl!)

del.performSelector(onMainThread:#selector(AppDelegate.registerSource) , with: theContext, waitUntilDone: false)
```

}

And AppDelegate class, in this class there are: methods that automatically adds Xcode in the normal routine of project creation (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, applicationWillResignActive, etc) I added the `sourcesToPing` parameter and the `registerSource()` method:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var sourcesToPing : [RunLoopContext] = Array()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return true
}

    func registerSource(sourceInfo:RunLoopContext)  {
    sourcesToPing.append(sourceInfo)
}

}
```

but the compiler get the following error , in `RunLoopSourceScheduleRoutine()` function:

```
argument '#selector' refers to instance method 'registerSources(source Info:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C
```

what is the problem ? and how does it solve?

Comment: Why does the error message complain about registerSource**s** if the method is called registerSource? Why don't you use GCD instead of performSelector (as suggested in an answer to your previous question)?

Comment: you're right, I did not know how to get the same result with GCD, now I understand that should I use:

dispatchQueue.main.async () {
   registerSource (theContext)
}
why should not specify the name of the class , like this: AppDelegate.registerSource (theContext)

Comment: That syntax of providing the class name as a prefix to the function name (e.g. `#selector(AppDelegate.registerSource(theContext))`) is a trick to let the compiler know know what class the `#selector` points to. It's not valid syntax for calling a normal instance method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PerformSelector is an Objective-C method that predates GCD (Grand Central Dispatch). It should be possible to do it that way, but selectors are not type-safe and are awkward to use.

I'm not sure what's wrong with your current code. As Martin points out in his comment, the error you're reporting is complaining about a method called `registerSources()` but you show code for a method called `registerSource()` (with no final "e".) If you want to get that code working you need to get to the bottom of that discrepency.

Instead, why not use GCD code like this:

```
dispatchQueue.main.async() {
  registerSource(theContext)
}
```

That will accomplish the same goal but using the more modern GCD

Comment: That is correct, but does not explain the error message in the question. Your answer could give the impression that performSelector cannot be used in Swift.

Comment: @MartinR, It's hard to tell what's going on with his current code. He's going to need to tell us about the registerSource/RegisterSources discrepency before we can help him with the `performSelector()` approach. Since GCD is better anyway, I decided to show him how to do that. I edited my answer to make it clearer that he could also use `performSelector()` but that he'd have to give us more info before we could help him. Better?

Comment: @DuncanC I'm trying to understand the Apple documentation at this link [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW37). In particular the part "Configuring Run Loop Sources"

Comment: @DuncanC then all methods and classes that I wrote should be the translation in swift language of such documentation.

Comment: @DuncanC If you look at the link, and find : "Configuring Run Loop Sources" you will see the methods that I have written, and how they are placed. A question that I have left is:  It is correct to place the method `registerSource()` , and the parameter `sourcesToPing` in the AppDelegate class?